# Angular2's TinyMCE Template Plugin Issues

Tags: angular, tinymce

I am trying to simply set up some templates in my imports for my tinymce editor but "templates:" doesn't seem to exist.

I get this error:
[ts]
Argument of type '{ skin_url: string; baseURL: string; plugins: string[]; toolbar: string; file_picker_types: strin...' is not assignable to parameter of type 'TinymceOptions'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'templates' does not exist in type 'TinymceOptions'.

Code Snippet:

```
@NgModule({
imports: [
  BrowserModule,
  FormsModule,
  HttpModule,
  ReactiveFormsModule,
  routing,
  TooltipModule,
  Ng2BootstrapModule,
  TypeaheadModule,
  ModalModule,
  TinymceModule.withConfig({skin_url:appContextPath+'/assets/tinymce/skins/lightgray',
  baseURL:appContextPath+'/assets/tinymce', plugins: ['preview','colorpicker','textcolor','link','table','lists','advlist','image','template'],
  toolbar: 'preview | forecolor backcolor image | styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect | tablecontrols | undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | template',
  file_picker_types: 'image',

//problem code here
  templates: 'somepath', 
...
```

The plugin for template and the toolbar option work fine, so I'm quite lost as to why the property value "templates" isn't recognized.

Am I missing something?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Edited after I read your error more closely. 
The `templates` option documentation is here: https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/template/#templates

From the error message you are passing a key to the Angular wrapper that it does not accept (in this case, the third-party wrapper you are using does not allow for a `templates` option). Please see their config file here: https://github.com/Ledzz/angular2-tinymce/blob/master/projects/angular2-tinymce-lib/src/lib/angular2-tinymce-lib.config.interface.ts
It lists all of your available options and `templates` is not included for this wrapper.

Comment: The problem is that there is an autofill for all the properties I can use and "templates" is not one of them despite the documentation saying otherwise. And I have tried every method angular suggest for linking a template as well as googling for forever. A plugin not having a defined feature is hard to debug, after all.

Comment: From your code, you might be using this TinyMCE Angular wrapper: https://github.com/Ledzz/angular2-tinymce

Comment: The documentation on configuration options for that third-party wrapper is limited and the link is broken:
https://github.com/Ledzz/angular2-tinymce#configure

As in the answer above, I'm thinking that because you have an autofill that the third-party wrapper used in the project does not support the "templates" option for its configuration.

Comment: After researching the third-party Angular wrapper you are using I edited my answer.  The documentation for that wrapper is sparse and has broken links.  It also has a number of upcoming features that are not yet implemented.